# My webcam doesn't work for browser based usage

Tags: macos, google-chrome, flash, webcam

My webcam doesn't work when I use it with the flash sites that use web cam.

It asks for permission and then I click allow and then nothing happens.

The webcam works with Skype.

Comment: Please state operating system version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be a common one. The solution should be simple: Try setting the [global permissions](https://blog.imeet.com/how-to-enable-your-webcam-and-microphone-on-mac-lion-os-x/) as well. [Here](http://www.userplane.com/blog/apple-adobe-flash-video/) is another tutorial for doing that.

Comment: Neither of those works

Comment: I also tried resetting the browser and also using disk utility to reset stuff